# Swift - how to convert hyphen/minus sign into + sign

Tags: string, swift, replace, converters

---

I am obtaining address in string variable from iOS reverse geocoding from below code.

```
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(imageLocation, completionHandler:
                    {(placemarks, error) in
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {                            
 if (error != nil) {println("reverse geodcode fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      textField.placeholder = "Address not found."              
     }
 else
    {
 if placemarks.count > 0
    {
var placemark:CLPlacemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark     
var locationAddress:NSArray = placemark.addressDictionary["FormattedAddressLines"]   as! NSArray
 var tmpAddress = locationAddress.componentsJoinedByString("\n")
 textField.text = tmpAddress as String
                                }
                            }
                        })
                })
```

tmpAddress variable has address - "2362-2658 W 12th St\nCity, State 20301\nCountry Name"

I need to change 2362-2658 into 2362+2658 in tmpAddress variable but i am not able to do so by

```
tmpAddress = tmpAddress.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "+")
```

or

```
tmpAddress = tmpAddress.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{2212}", withString: " ")
```

Please can someone suggest why stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString above is not working and how can this be accomplished.

Comment: I had looked at that earlier during my research - It did not work for me. I tried converting " " into "+' which works but converting "-" into "+" does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tmpAddress = tmpAddress.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "+")`

This replaces '-' with '+'

The first parameter is the search string, and the second is the replacement string.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. My be "-' between two numbers is not simple minus sign?

Comment: Then, print out the original output string and copy the '-' symbol from the command line and paste it in the code? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var str =  "2362-2658 W 12th St\nCity, State 20301\nCountry Name"
var start = str.startIndex
var end = advance(start, str.characters.count)
var modStr = str .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "+", options:.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end))
```

Or simplified:

```
var modStr = str .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "+")
```

Your issue is you are replacing an empty space " ", with a "-". Not a "-" with "+" in your original code.

Comment: simplified option does not work. I tried first option but getting error "String does not have member named character " at line - var end = advance(start, str.characters.count)

Comment: I tried below just to get passed to that error but still "-" is not converted to "+" var str =  tmpAddress
                                var start = str.startIndex
                                var end = advance(start, 9)
                                var modStr = str .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "+", options:.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end))